# Will iMessage work on an iPhone 6 Plus from Saudi Arabia?

Tags: iphone

Will iMessage work on an iPhone 6 Plus bought in Saudi Arabia? I'm not interested in Facetime, but want to know whether iMessage will work.

Comment: You should ask this on a different [stack exchange site](http://travel.stackexchange.com) for better visibility with travelers. You might catch someone who just came from there who can verify

Comment: why not? it is just a standard iPhone.

Comment: Middle East iPhones have limitations, but idk which countries specifically

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the carriers

- *STC* is working
- *zain* used to work but now it is not
- don't know about *mobily*